# OpenSSH adds <IPv6>%2 to known_hosts

Tags: ssh, ipv6, ssh-keys, systemd, known-hosts

When I connect to a CentOS 7 host with IPv6 my ssh client always adds `<IPv6 host addr>%2` to `known_hosts` even though the host key for this host (with the host's IPv6 address) is already present in `known_hosts`.

What does the `%2` stand for? I'm using the unmodified OpenSSH from CentOS 7 which is version 6.6.1p1-25, release 25.el7_2.

Update: A comment mentioned name resolution as a possible problem. Indeed I'm using systemd-resolved on the client machine. When I remove `resolved` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (`hosts` option) the problem does not occur anymore.  This is with `systemd-resolved-219-19.el7_2.7.x86_64`).

**Update (Feb 2017):** I just noticed [systemd-resolved bug 4465](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4465) so the behavior I noticed was/is just a bug which will be fixed in a later version of systemd.

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote host?

Comment: ssh root@<HOSTNAME>

Comment: You're not using an IP address? What does the hostname resolve to?

Comment: No I'm not using the an IP address in the CLI directly. The hostname has one DNS record for ipv4 and one for ipv6 (A/AAAA). `dig -t AAAA` shows that it resolves to `<IPv6 host addr>`.

Comment: Is the address a link-local one (`fe80:…`) or a global one? In the former case it'd be expected; in the latter – a ssh bug.

Comment: The target hostname uses a public IPv6 address. I only have a link-local address on my eth0 interface (together with a public address) and my default-gateway has (only) a link-local address.

Comment: Go ahead and make an answer, then. People will not look for answers in the question body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different classes of IPv6 address have different scope. You will come across addresses of scope host (for example `::1`), link (for example `fe80::200:5eff:fe00:5342`), global (for example `2001:db8::1`).

When an address with scope link is used on a host with more than one link, the `%` notation is used to indicate which link the address is used on.

All addresses starting with `fe80:` are in the link-local scope and may need an interface specification. Interfaces can be specified by their name or their number. For example on the computer I am typing this from `eth0` is interface number `2`, so `fe80::200:5eff:fe00:5342%2` and `fe80::200:5eff:fe00:5342%eth0` would be equivalent. Either notation would indicate the host with link-local address `fe80::200:5eff:fe00:5342` on the network which my `eth0` interface is connected to.